# Akka Stream Graphs - How to test PartitionWith from akka.stream.contrib

Tags: scala, scalatest, akka-stream

I wrote a simple test to explore the `PartitionWith` graph functionality from `akka.stream.contrib`. Here is the code snippet:

```
class Scratch
    extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PartitionWith"))
    with WordSpecLike
    with ScalaFutures
    with Eventually
    with Matchers {

  "PartitionWith" should {
    "split source" in {
      val source: Source[Either[Int, String], NotUsed] = Source(List(Left(1), Right("one")))
      val leftHeadSink = Sink.head[Int]
      val rightHeadSink = Sink.head[String]

      val flow = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(source, leftHeadSink, rightHeadSink)((_, _, _)) {
        implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[(NotUsed, Future[Int], Future[String])] => (s, l, r) =>
          import GraphDSL.Implicits._

          val pw = builder.add(PartitionWith.apply[Either[Int, String], Int, String](identity))

          s ~> pw.in
          pw.out0 ~> l.in
          pw.out1 ~> r.in

          ClosedShape
      })

      val event = flow.run()
      event._2.futureValue shouldBe 1     // first check
      event._3.futureValue shouldBe "one" // second check
    }
```

When I run the above test, it throws me this error:

```
The future returned an exception of type: java.util.NoSuchElementException, with message: head of empty stream.
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: The future returned an exception of type: java.util.NoSuchElementException, with message: head of empty stream.
```

It seems like it fails in the second check because the `rightHeadSink` is empty. I'm wondering if the `Right("one")` in `Source(List(Left(1), Right("one")))` is never processed??

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first `Sink.head` completes, it seems like the whole stream is completed, so the second sink fails to retrieve its element.

Try to test with 2 `Sink.seq`s instead of 2 `Sink.head`s to avoid a precocious termination of your stream.